# How to get class name in a method inside this class

Tags: qore

Is there any method how to get class name inside a method in the same class? Or in general, if I have an instance of a class and I need to know which class is it instance of?

Answer (score 3):

In Qore (according to the tag on the question), you need to use the [<object>::className()](https://docs.qore.org/current/lang/html/class_qore_1_1zzz8objectzzz9.html#a284be71278d0b081544ba675a3d1ead5) pseudo-method on your object.

ex:

```
prompt% qore -nX '(new Mutex()).className()'
"Mutex"
```

If you are in the class, use this pseudo-method on the automatic `self` variable:

```
prompt% qore -ne '
class T {
    string getClassName() {
        return self.className();
    }
}
class U inherits T {}
printf("%s\n", (new U()).getClassName());
'
U
```

Alternatively you can also use the [get_class_name()](https://docs.qore.org/current/lang/html/group__misc__functions.html#gaa9a0d3f277ef8cbdc99fe146dd3db49b) function as in the following example:

```
prompt% qore -nX 'get_class_name(new Mutex())'
"Mutex"
```

Note that if a class defines a method with the same name as a pseudo-method, the class method will be called instead, and the pseudo-method cannot be called, in which case you have to use the function mentioned above.

Comment: note that there is also [instanceof operator](https://docs.qore.org/current/lang/html/operators.html#instanceof)

Answer (score 0):

Please see http://php.net/manual/pl/function.get-class.php.

```
get_class($this);
```

Comment: question was about qore, not php